# Analog Devices Filter Wizard Schematic Question

Tags: analog, schematics, active-filter

I am using filter wizard to help me design an active multiple feedback bandpass filter. I understand the parts of the schematic that show the stages of the filter, like this: [image: figure 1]

However, I am struggling to figure out what other parts of the schematic mean. Specifically, this part:[image: figure 2]

Anyone know what is meant by the second set of diagrams?

Comment: note your high-frequency active-filter response will NOT BE CONTROLLED by the opamps. Even with 10Mhz UGBW opamps, the attenuation near 10MHz, or higher than 10MHz, is not controlled by the opamp. Thus you need passive RC LPFs in the filter chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacitors are power bypass. It’s always a good idea for reducing the impedance of the power supply close to the ICs.

The rest seems to be a software bug. That’s the kind of thing you would do if you have extra unused amplifiers left over in a package.

The fact that it’s numbering all of the amplifiers as a quad U1A-C and indicating 1/2 on each, seems to be part of the same bug.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. If i am using a different op amp from the one in the schematic should i use the bypass cap values that my op amp's dats sheet gives, or stick with the one on the filter wizard schematic?

Comment: @Saunders I would go with the datasheet. But in slow analog circuits this is seldom critical.